# Bosh Set up using openfire

Tags: xmpp, openfire

I am using openfire in windows to set up bosh connection manager...the installation is successfull but wen i give the url http://localhost:9090/bosh it says

HTTP ERROR: 404

NOT_FOUND
RequestURI=/http-bind/

Powered by Jetty://

tried http://localhost:9090/http-bind/
gives the same error

can anyone pls tel me wat s happening...
how do i troubleshoot
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try setting the port to `7070` I believe that's the default BOSH port for Openfire. Go to the Admin consol and check out http binding (what bosh does is bind the xmpp protocol to a http request response model.... basically)

```
http://127.0.0.1:9090/http-bind.jsp
```

**Edit:** Actually what do you mean by "give the url"? are you putting that into the browser?
The admin consol url is `http://127.0.0.1:9090/index.jsp`

Answer (score 2):

Try using `POST` rather than `GET` containing a `<body/>` element, as specified in [XEP-0206](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0206.html):

```
POST /bosh HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 275

<body content='text/xml; charset=utf-8'
      from='user@localhost'
      hold='1'
      rid='1573741820'
      to='localhost'
      wait='60'
      xml:lang='en'
      xmpp:version='1.0'
      xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'
      xmlns:xmpp='urn:xmpp:xbosh'/>
```

Comment: It's not a file.  It's protocol that you send using HTTP.  You'll want to use a library like Strophe.js (http://code.stanziq.com/strophe/) to send that protocol.

Comment: yea i am using strophe.js but even then i am gettin this error

Comment: I am unable to access openfire over https : --https://127.0.0.1:9091/http-bind.jsp

Answer (score 1):

The BOSH request requires a BODY.

If your `HTTP Bind Settings` do not allow for `Script Syntax` then you will get a `404` error for a GET request.  If you enable Script Syntax, i.e. Allows BOSH clients with limited access to connect to the server, then you will get a `400` error for a GET request, so you will at least know that Jetty is listening on that port.

[image]

To send a valid request you should make a POST request with a body, e.g. with cURL you can run (line breaks added for clarity):

```
curl -X POST -d "<body content='text/xml; charset=utf-8' 
    from='user@localhost' 
    hold='1' 
    rid='1573741820' 
    to='localhost' 
    wait='60' 
    xml:lang='en' 
    xmpp:version='1.0' 
    xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' xmlns:xmpp='urn:xmpp:xbosh'/>" 
        http://desktop-nquceg9:7070/http-bind/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `Script Syntax` to `Enable` at **http://127.0.0.1:9090/http-bind.jsp**